# linux find regexp

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a script where I want to find all direct subdirectories that is purely numerical in a folder and copy them to a specified destination. I have issues to get regexp to work with `+` and `*` in `find`. The folder structure in the example is as follows:

```
0/
1/
2/
3/
3.02asd/
3a/
4/
44/
45/
451/
452/
453/
4531/
4532/
45321/
45322/
45323/
666aa/
66a/
66aaa/
temp27/
```

I have gotten this to work with the following commands:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "[0-9]" | while read f
do
    mv $f $TESTPATH
done

find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "[0-9][0-9]" | while read f
do
    mv $f $TESTPATH
done

find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9]" | while read f
do
    mv $f $TESTPATH
done

find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" | while read f
do
    mv $f $TESTPATH
done

find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" | while read f
do
    mv $f $TESTPATH
done
```

Not very nice but it works, but this should probably be possible with something like:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "[0-9]+"
```

or

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "[0-9][0-9]*"
```

But it seems that `+` doesn't work and `*` is wildcard it seems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `-regex` instead of `-name`, e.g.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex ".*/[0-9]*"
```

Comment: Becareful, you have to put the `-maxdepth 1` option before `-type d`.

Comment: @Daimrod: actually I think it works OK either way around - I just tested it to be sure. Performance is probably better if you put the `-maxdepth 1` first though.

Comment: Yes both works, but I think it's faster and at least you don't have a warning. ;)